# PreparedStatement throwing index is out of range when it is not out of range

Tags: java, sql-server, jdbc

I am generating a table and inserting the data into that table.  The table is created from data that has complex relationships.  We created this so users of our BI tool could easily deal with the data.

We have a bunch of these tables that get created each one is different based on the user generated data.  In one case we are getting index out of range exception. When inspecting the meta data it is not out of range.

The exact exception message is:

`com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The index 13 is out of range`.

The generated insert statement is:

```
INSERT INTO [F22_AF] ([frcId],[eId],[aId],[dateCreated],[DateofThing],[Wasthisaninjury],[Whowainjured],[WhowainjuredFNAME],[WhowainjuredLNAME],[Whatwasinvolved],[WhatwasinvolvedDATA],[WhatOptionsWereAvailable],[AccidentWitnessed]) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)
```

When the value for accident witnessed is set the exception is thrown.  When the value is about to be set I printed the column index and the value:

> 13 : AccidentWitnessed = false

When it fails I printed out the meta data from the insert statement and got this:

parameterMetaData.getParameterCount()=13

ColIndex - Type || Class

1 - int || java.lang.Integer

2 - int || java.lang.Integer

3 - int || java.lang.Integer

4 - datetime || java.sql.Timestamp

5 - datetime || java.sql.Timestamp

6 - nvarchar || java.lang.String

7 - int || java.lang.Integer

8 - nvarchar || java.lang.String

9 - nvarchar || java.lang.String

10 - int || java.lang.Integer

11 - nvarchar || java.lang.String

12 - int || java.lang.Integer

13 - bit || java.lang.Boolean

When I try to set col index 13 I get Index Out Of Range, however according to the meta data it exists!  If it didn't exist I would get another out of range exception.

The same code works for a different set of data.

Can anyone explain why this error would occur when the column index exists?

Comment: Did you try with zero-based indices? And if it's not that, you should post the exact code you use to build your statement and to execute it.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik Indices in Java's `PreparedStatement` are 1-based, so I wouldn't expect that to be the cause of the problem.

Comment: @Jesper Without any code it's kind of guesswork what exactly is going on. There might be intermittent code that converts from 1- to 0-based, or god knows what else.

Comment: Can you give us the case you use to fill your statement, like `statement.setObject(13,...)`?

Comment: Maybe the field is defined as BIT(0) in the table and the error is misleading us? Swap with the before last field in SQL.

Comment: @JoopEggen Yes swapping 13 and 12 creates out of range on 12.  I can not find anything in the TSQL spec that metions bit size.

Comment: Then certainly something is wrong with the field definition. If not correctable (TINYINT(1)?) then you could do a SELECT query with a getObject and inspect the java getClass().

Comment: I think this question asnwer is not correct I will add mine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My advice?   Believe the JVM.  It doesn't matter what you think.

You're not looking at the right spot to understand what's going wrong.  Write a small, self-contained example and run it in a debugger.  You'll be able to see where the code is going awry that way.

Comment: Code Error - the wrong Prepared Statement Object was calling setBoolean

Answer (score 0):

Same error also occured for me when I used `Hibernate`. But the exception does not depend to hibernate. This exception is depend to `JDBC` or `Database` version.In mine database is oracle and got same exception.Reason was the `ojdbc` bug which I used. In `Prepared Statement` if I passed more than 7 parameters I got exception.This is a bug. The solution is changing `ojdbc`.